# Lemmatizzazione di un participio presente come sostantivo o aggettivo a sé stante

Tags: adjectives, nouns

«In italiano moderno, il participio presente è prevalentemente forma aggettivale (assente, circostante, morente, presente, ubbidiente) o nominale (dirigente, conoscente, parente, tangente, vedente)» ([cit.](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/participio_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)). Cioè, «il participio presente […] oggi è usato soprattutto come aggettivo o sostantivo» ([cit.](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/participio_(La_grammatica_italiana)/)).

Tuttavia alcuni participî presenti vengono registrati nei vocabolari/dizionari come lemmi a sé stanti, riconoscendone così in qualche misura l'autonomia semantica, altri no. Esistono regole condivise di [lemmatizzazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tipi-di-lemma_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)? Oppure l'unica regola è l'uso, se un vocabolo viene utilizzato spesso viene inserito come lemma, altrimenti no? Conoscete fonti al riguardo?

Answer (score 2):

Credo che la risposta sia presente nella pagina che hai linkato:

> Il criterio della lemmatizzazione può variare da lingua a lingua e da dizionario a dizionario

Che io sappia non c'è una regola comune al riguardo. Il fatto che un participio presente venga elevato a lemma **potrebbe** dipendere dalla frequenza con cui viene usato in modo indipendente, quindi mi aspetterei di trovare "dirigente", "tangente", "ubbidiente", ma non "saltante".